# How to associate array keys to a specific prior key?

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I currently have an array that stores a lot of questions, question types, and answers. Now the answers can be of different lengths. For example:

```
  0 => array:222 [▼
    0 => "(Type): multiplechoice"
    1 => "(Question): Which of the following is true about pre-test imagery?"
    2 => "(A): People with a cranial fault can visualize the muscle being strong and make it go strong, while people without a cranial faults cannot."
    3 => "(B): If Governing Vessel (GV) 20 tests weak, it also means they have a cranial fault. This is on the midline at the apex of the head."
    4 => "(C): The three most common cranial faults are TMJ, occiput and sphenoid"
    5 => "(D): All of the above"
    6 => "(Correct): D"
    7 => "(Type): multiplechoice"
    8 => "(Question): Which of the following is not true about the TMJ?"
    9 => "(A): Every single TMJ nerve pathway goes through the mesencephalon in the midbrain."
    10 => "(B): When you work on the TMJ it is a neurological back-up for the entire body."
    11 => "(C): To correct press on the glabella with one hand as you press of the back of the head with the other as the patient touches the chin with two fingers and breathes in only one time."
    12 => "(Correct): C"
    13 => "(Type): truefalse"
    14 => "(Question): To test for a deficiency of the four primary neurotransmitters, point the edge of a magnet straight in at each of the four corresponding cranial bon ▶"
    15 => "(A): True"
    16 => "(B): False"
    17 => "(Correct): A"
```

The problem I face is that each question includes a `question`, `type` and `correct` value, but the there could be varying amounts of answers - 10+ answers could be possible.

My current approach was to work through the array and create new arrays for for questions, types, and corrects, and then loop through the arrays and pair pair question's values by the keys. Due to the fact there being different amounts of answers, this unfortunately did not end of being beneficial.

What could be a possible approach to this? How can I associate all the values to the appropriate question?

Thanks so much for any help and hints!

Comment: Why is key 36 in-between key 12 and 13?

Comment: post the expected result

Comment: @mickmackusa with 222 items that is not an issue. But sure the first regex can be replaced with a strpos or even substr. Either way I doubt it will make much difference in real life.

Comment: Also Mick, have you seen the performance time on your code? https://3v4l.org/0eJvo/perf#output . Poor and uninspired huh?....

Comment: @Andreas Phew, for a moment there I thought the world was upside down... I arbitrarily extended the input array by multiplying the batch of 3 questions 8x to performance test.  [Andreas' code](https://3v4l.org/Jf8A7/perf#output) [My code](https://3v4l.org/qV763/perf#output) It seems to me that my answer performs better, but I didn't time trial each code 50 times then average them.  My earlier assertion came down to number of iterated function calls, it doesn't feel like best practice to me to run so many separate preg_match calls versus one big one.

Comment: @mickmackusa I see your point, but our answers result in two completly different arrays too. There is no way you can create an array with named keys with only one regex. My code gives an array with named keys and no empty items, yours is more a "generic" array with empty items when there is less than four ansers. And since the question states there can be 10+ answers, your array will have a lot of empty keys. All of which will have to be `if !=""` on output. Mine can just be outputed the way it is. Keep in mind all those ifs takes time. All extra coding takes time. But it's a preference Iguess

Comment: @mickmackusa I'm not saying your array is wrong. The question itself should perhaps be closed due to there is no answer on the question, he asks a broad question without any answer. But he is clear about asking for a good setup of an array. And in my opinion, named keys is good for this. I mean you can easily check `if $res[$questionNumber]["Type"] == "truefalse"` if that is something you need to concider. Or `if $userAnswer == $res[$questionNumber]["Correct"]`. In my opinion it makes the code easy to read. But that is a preference. I know that.

Comment: @Chris Can you please explain where your array data comes from?  Is this from a txt file?  a database?  Also important, what is your expected output?  How are you printing this to screen?  We may be able to optimize your approach if you provide us with all of the relevant information.  Please show your code.

Comment: @mickmackusa I don't remember your answer in detail but I think you should be able to make it adapt to unlimited answers with `\(([A-Z]{1})\)`. But still I don't see it as a, developer friendly approach. It may be user friendly by running fast but it would be a nightmare for a developer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can group the questions like this?
https://3v4l.org/dvZVZ

```
$arr = array(
0 => "(Type): multiplechoice",
1 => "(Question): Which of the following is true about pre-test imagery?",
2 => "(A): People with a cranial fault can visualize the muscle being strong and make it go strong, while people without a cranial faults cannot.",
3 => "(B): If Governing Vessel (GV) 20 tests weak, it also means they have a cranial fault. This is on the midline at the apex of the head.",
4 => "(C): The three most common cranial faults are TMJ, occiput and sphenoid",
5 => "(D): All of the above",
6 => "(Correct): D",
7 => "(Type): multiplechoice",
8 => "(Question): Which of the following is not true about the TMJ?",
9 => "(A): Every single TMJ nerve pathway goes through the mesencephalon in the midbrain.",
10 => "(B): When you work on the TMJ it is a neurological back-up for the entire body.",
11 => "(C): To correct press on the glabella with one hand as you press of the back of the head with the other as the patient touches the chin with two fingers and breathes in only one time.",
12 => "(Correct): C",
13 => "(Type): truefalse",
14 => "(Question): To test for a deficiency of the four primary neurotransmitters, point the edge of a magnet straight in at each of the four corresponding cranial bon ▶",
15 => "(A): True",
16 => "(B): False",
17 => "(Correct): A");


$j=-1;
$res = array();
Foreach($arr as $value){
    If(substr($value,0,6)== "(Type)"){
        $j++;
    }
    preg_match("/\((.*?)\): (.*)/", $value, $match);
    $res[$j][$match[1]]= $match[2];

}

Var_dump($res);
```

Edited to remove one regex.
However according to 3v4l the system time has gone from 0.003 seconds to 0.040 seconds with this change.
You be the judge Chris, some people swear on regex slowing down without knowing or trying.

Comment: @Chris thank you! I don't know how you intended to use the array but maybe this is a better way? https://3v4l.org/dvZVZ

Comment: Wouldn't it be faster to use `strpos($value,'(Type')===0`?

Comment: @mickmackusa maybe it is. But it's only 222 items to check. I think any difference in speed can easily be eaten up by any other code not being 100% optimized.

Comment: In the absence of more information from the OP, I like your approach better than mine now. (+1) This is how I would modify your approach if the project was mine: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/464a07d71b51d9c9e8abe5f08f605b2de891f1bf